# What would Object.freeze(globalThis) do?

Tags: javascript

For science, I tried the following in jsfiddle & dev console of my own browser:

```
Object.freeze(globalThis)
```

I got the following error as a result:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot freeze
    at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
```

What would have that line of code done?

The goal is an intrinsic one; to try to learn through experimentation as a developer.

Comment: `Object.freeze(window)` might be a little clearer when asking your question

Comment: *Object.freeze* would disable extensions on the global object, that would disable things like global function and variable declarations.

Comment: @MisterJojo—do you have references to documentation (ECMA-262 would be good) that state what should happen? I can't find anything directly, only that *Object.freeze* calls the internal [`[[SetIntegrityLeve]]`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-setintegritylevel) which then calls the internal `[[PreventExtensions]]` method, but that's where the trail ends.

Comment: @MisterJojo—clearly it makes sense functionally, but I'd expect the algorithm for `O.[[PreventExtensions]]()` explicitly state "if O is the global object, return false" or similar. I can't find that anywhere in ECMA-262 (there is no algorithm for \[\[PreventExtensions\]\] that I can find).